# Visual Studio 2017 Compile DirectX8

Tags: c++, mfc, directx

I'm working on an old project that is using DirectX 8, I wonder if there is a way to make Visual Studio 2017 compile the code while still using DirectX8.

Windows SDK = 10.0.16299.0

Toolset = msvc141

I'm using the modern look of MFC applications as sample project, but it's probably has nothing to do with it as it happens only when I include `D3DX8.h` for example, I get a lot of syntax errors on DirectX side.

I wonder if there is a way to work on directx 8 without me having to keep using Visual C++ 6.0.

```
1>c:\mmorpg\directx\dx3d8\dxf\dxsdk\include\d3d8types.h(155): error C2011: '_D3DLIGHTTYPE': 'enum' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\d3d9types.h(180): note: see declaration of '_D3DLIGHTTYPE'
1>c:\mmorpg\directx\dx3d8\dxf\dxsdk\include\d3d8types.h(189): error C2011: '_D3DSHADEMODE': 'enum' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\d3d9types.h(214): note: see declaration of '_D3DSHADEMODE'
1>c:\mmorpg\directx\dx3d8\dxf\dxsdk\include\d3d8types.h(196): error C2011: '_D3DFILLMODE': 'enum' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\d3d9types.h(221): note: see declaration of '_D3DFILLMODE'
1>c:\mmorpg\directx\dx3d8\dxf\dxsdk\include\d3d8types.h(208): error C2011: '_D3DBLEND': 'enum' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\d3d9types.h(228): note: see declaration of '_D3DBLEND'
1>c:\mmorpg\directx\dx3d8\dxf\dxsdk\include\d3d8types.h(225): error C2011: '_D3DBLENDOP': 'enum' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\d3d9types.h(255): note: see declaration of '_D3DBLENDOP'
1>c:\mmorpg\directx\dx3d8\dxf\dxsdk\include\d3d8types.h(234): error C2011: '_D3DTEXTUREADDRESS': 'enum' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\d3d9types.h(264): note: see declaration of '_D3DTEXTUREADDRESS'
```

Answer (score 3):

The Windows SDK does not support DirectX 8 development. Since the first time DirectX became 'part of the OS' was DirectX 9.0c with Windows XP Service Pack 2, the Windows SDK has only ever had Direct3D 9 or later headers.

The last legacy DirectX SDK to support DirectX 8 was *August 2007* (the end of life release of the DirectX SDK was *June 2010*). That was using VS 2005 / VS 2008 with the Windows SDK 6.0.

There are definitely challenges mixing the legacy DirectX SDK with the Windows SDK. There are instructions on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) for using the June 2010 version, but as I noted that doesn't include Direct3D 8.

See [DirectX SDKs of a certain age](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/) and [A Brief History of Windows SDKs](https://walbourn.github.io/a-brief-history-of-windows-sdks/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information! That makes much more sense now. Would it be possible creating a Windows XP Machine and using Visual Studio there so that I can continue and develop there without worrying about the windows environment? Or can you please suggest what can I do in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the library and include directory of <winsdk6.0a> and  to your project
PlatformToolsets select v100

props file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="Current"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx -->

    <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
        <WinSDKDir>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A</WinSDKDir>
        <WinSDKInc>$(WinSDKDir)\include</WinSDKInc>
        <WinSDKLib>$(WinSDKDir)\lib</WinSDKLib>
        <DX8SDKDir>$(UserSDKDir)\DirectX\DX8.1bSDK</DX8SDKDir>
        <DX8SDKInc>$(DX8SDKDir)\include</DX8SDKInc>
        <DX8SDKLib>$(DX8SDKDir)\lib</DX8SDKLib>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <ClCompile>
            <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(WinSDKInc);$(DX8SDKInc);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
        </ClCompile>
        <Link>
            <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(WinSDKLib);$(DX8SDKLib);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
            <AdditionalDependencies>d3d8.lib;DxErr8.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
            <AdditionalDependencies Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">d3dx8d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
            <AdditionalDependencies Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">d3dx8.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score -1):

From the error line : 
`c:\mmorpg\directx\dx3d8\dxf\dxsdk\include\d3d8types.h(155): error C2011: '_D3DLIGHTTYPE': 'enum' type redefinition 1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared\d3d9types.h(180): note: see declaration of '_D3DLIGHTTYPE'`

=> you are including obviously two version of directX headers `d3d8types.h` and `d3d9types.h` , referencing the exact same symbols.
 I think it should be only one of them included.

To trace what cause the include of `d3d9types.h` file, in Visual Studio, you can activate the showIncludes compiler option :

[Show includes compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx)

Comment: So should i add in the Windows SDK d3d9types.h this?
#ifndef _d3d9TYPES_H_ || _D3D8TYPES_H_
#define _d3d9TYPES_H_

Comment: you should not touch directX headers but understand how is it that you have already d3d9types.h included previously. You can use this option to see  the tree of include(s)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx

Comment: I see that it includes first the windows SDK and then the directx, so i tried to move the directx include before the windows SDK and then i get this error again in winnt.h of `C2146 - syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PVOID64'` which i saw in different topics in stackoverflow that directx should be included last if that error comes.

Comment: This answer is in no way helpful. It neither identifies the core issue, nor does it propose a solution.

Comment: This still doesn't identify the core issue. As explained in Chuck Walbourn's answer, DirectX is now part of the Windows SDK. The OP is using a Windows SDK that includes DirectX, while trying to reference a dedicated DirectX SDK. There is no reason to further diagnose the issue. This *is* the issue, and Chuck Walbourn's answer also provides links to documentation that may help in solving the issue. This answer still isn't helpful.

Comment: Chuck Walbourn's answer is the specific answer to the issue. My answer is the generic answer to the link error and provides way of understanding what happen and why stuff does not work. Both are valuable